# JSON value into URL

Tags: javascript, json

I want to put a value from my JSON into a URL for the user to be able navigate to an individual page.

Example: in my JSON I have:

```
{
  userId: "123456789"
}
```

And I want them to be able to click on a link and be sent to: `https://example.com/"userId"/blah/blah"`.

How can I achieve this by using JavaScript? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append the key to the url if its known.

```
a = {
  userId: "123456789"
}

url = "https://example.com/userId/" +a['userId']
```

If key is not known and to be fetched from JSON, you can use `Object.keys` to get the keys and append it to the URL followed by its value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ${} to wrap your userid to dynamically change the value of "userId" based on the selected user. simply replace "userid" with ${userid} in the link.

```
url = `https://example.com/${userId}/blah/blah`
```